# How to detect events in an Azure Devops Board extension

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

I'm trying to create an Azure DevOps Board extension that detects the main work item events: item created, assigned/unassined to user, added to sprint, state change (todo -> wip -> finished), etc.

The equivalent Jira plugin can be easily developed following this guide: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/writing-jira-event-listeners-with-the-atlassian-event-library/

However in the case of Azure Devops Boards I can't finde any clear indication to do this. Could you provide some sample/hint/documentation to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use an extension to do this. Extensions are really just front end components. You'll have to use a service hook with a webhook.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops

Comment: This will work! As an alternative is it possible to implement a service  integration like the one for Trello? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops#available-services

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: Well, it's not clear how to do it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-service-hook?view=azure-devops#custom-consumer-service). The documentation doesn't really show how to reference the consumer service (external URL...) and implement the "Supported actions", e.g. invoke an external API.